# What should I test for my angular controller?

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine

I've learning to use Karma to test my angularjs app.  However, not a few of my controllers use multiple services which are http requests that retrieve json which is then loaded to the page.  I've been stuck because of two questions I can't answer.  1) How do I mock these services 2) what exactly should I test for my controller  Question 2 I find difficult to answer because controller functions depend on services which I use in other controllers.  Anyway, let me show one of my controllers and then, the "library" housing my services:

One of my controllers

```
angular.module('ccApp')
.controller('CountriesCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams',              '$location','countryInfo', 'getCountries', 'countriesCache', 'getNeighbors', 
   'buildCountry', '$timeout', '$q',
    function($scope, $routeParams, $location, countryInfo, getCountries,     countriesCache, getNeighbors, 
    buildCountry, $timeout, $q){            
    getCountries.countriesObject.then(function(response){
        $scope.geocountries = response.data.geonames;
    },
    function(response){
        alert("error");
    });

    $scope.toCountry = function(geocountry){
        getNeighbors(geocountry.geonameId)
        .then(function(response){
            buildCountry(geocountry, response);
            var path = '/countries/'+countryInfo.name+'/capital';
            $location.path(path);
        }),
        function(response){
            alert('Error');
        };
    };
    $scope.goHome = function(){
        $location.path('/');
    };
```

}]);

What here should I test in the controller spec?

Here's the library where the services are housed:

```
angular.module('library', [])
.service('countryInfo', function(){
    var country = {
        name: '',
        pop: '',
        area: '',
        capital: '',
        code: '',
        capPop: '',
        numNeigh: 0,
        neighbors: []
    };
    return country;
 })
 .factory('countriesCache', ['$cacheFactory', function($cacheFactory){
    return $cacheFactory('countriesCached');
  }])
 .factory('getCountries', ['$http', function($http){
    var request = {
            username: 'vman'
        };
    return { countriesObject : $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'http://api.geonames.org/countryInfoJSON', 
            params: request
        })};
  }])
  .factory('getCountry', ['$http', function($http){
    return function(countryCode){
        return $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'http://api.geonames.org/countryInfoJSON',
            params: { username: 'vman', country: countryCode }
        });
    };
  }])
  .factory('getNeighbors', ['$http', function($http){
    return function(geonameId){
        return $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'http://api.geonames.org/neighboursJSON',
            params: { username: 'vman', geonameId: geonameId }
        });
    };
  }])
  .factory('buildCountry', ['countryInfo', '$q', '$timeout',      function(countryInfo, $q, $timeout){
    return function(geocountry, response){
        countryInfo.name = geocountry.countryName;
        countryInfo.code = geocountry.countryCode;
        countryInfo.pop = geocountry.population;
        countryInfo.area = geocountry.areaInSqKm;
        countryInfo.capital = geocountry.capital;
        countryInfo.neighbors = response.data.geonames;
        countryInfo.numNeigh = response.data.geonames.length;
    };
  }])
  .run(['$rootScope', '$location', function($rootScope, $location) {
      $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeError', function() {
         $location.path('/error');
     });
  }]);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. The following snippet creates a mock of the above service:

   module(function($provide) {
           $provide.service('demoService', function() {
                   this.isDemoApi = jasmine.createSpy('isDemoApi');
           });
       });

   //Getting reference of the mocked service

   var mockDemoSvc;

   ```
   inject(function(demoService) {
       mockDemoSvc = demoService;
   });
   ```
2. To test the controller, firstly you will have to mock all the services which this controller is using by using the above code. 
   This would help to test controller APIs seperatly. Then you can go ahead to test APIs which are binded with the scope, like: `toCountry()`

Comment: @suneet_bansal Thanks for laying out the Mock in detail.  I will try this later. So, do I understand you correctly, I am not testing the actual service, but the scope function which calls the service?  More specifically, I am testing that the scope function calls a service, in this case, a purely mock service